# Google Maps and java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android, google-maps

> 02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348): Writing exception to parcel
>   02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348):
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for
>   user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL 02-14 13:09:38.184:
>   E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
>   02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at
>   android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
>   02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at
>   com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
>   02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
>   02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
>   02-14 13:09:38.184: E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 02-14 13:09:38.184:
>   E/DatabaseUtils(2348):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native
>   Method)

I've updated my app. But I can't use Google Maps API. When I open activity used Google Maps it shows the log above.
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL added to permissions.

```
 <permission
        android:name="my.app.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="my.app.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

Comment: add your manifest permissions also.....

Comment: I did it. "...added to permissions."

Comment: i mean to say post your manifest permissions here so all can have a look.

Comment: Ready. But I think it will not help./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the uses-permission element is not in the application element. I accidentally pasted it in there once, and Android Studio doesn't tell you that's a problem. Once I moved it out, it fixed the issue.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.someapp.app" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

  <application ...>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` is a signature level permission. Your app will not be able to use it until and unless it has the same signature as the system.

So add the below permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

Comment: You can achieve unless you either are the creator or the system build, or collaborating with them such that they are willing to sign your apk with their certificate. In other words, this is off limits for most developers.

Comment: I think you need to generate the signed apk. Exact solution don't know.

Comment: I've already used it. I've tried to use release signature. It doesnt work. It makes me crazy.

Comment: Yes. I usually used the same wrapper for all my apps. The Maps ALWAYS worked correctly. Until today morning.